# Jquery Tabs 1.8 ajax content > #history problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-tabs, unobtrusive-javascript

Hey! I'm trying to load jQuery content in the same container (div#realContent) and it seems that when I use the a 'title' to enter the div ID (all links the same title) the history stop working.

You can enter here http://home.d23.com.uy/fermata/ user: fermata pass: fermata , and see what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: ONLY ENABLE "CORO FERMATA" AND "FERMATA NINOS" BUTTONS. NO SUBMENU YET  AND ANY OTHER BUTTON.

Answer (score 0):

It is online now, and the history problem still happening.

Check it out at http://www.fermata.com.uy

Maybe the problem is that it's using tabs and it's not tabs what it should use.

Thanks,
Gaston.